# Using Scalar Types in Interfaces | Abstract Classes

Tags: php, interface, abstract-class

I'm trying to get to grips with scalar types and type-hinting in PHP. More specifically, I'm trying to create some example interfaces to try and learn how I can use interfaces in my projects and see if I can make some really useful class templates as such.

From my understanding, an interface defines the methods without defining what they do. Giving developers flexibility to create multiple classes based around the same principle but executed differently (e.g. creating a Database interface and having a PDOHandler and a MysqliHandler class.

To me, I took this to mean you might be able to type-hint parameters without having to actually do it inside each and every class.

I set up an experiment to test this and used the below code:

```
<?php
    #commenting this out allows ->init(4) to work with foobar
    declare(strict_types = 1); 

    interface Foo
    {
        public function init(?string $str);
    }

    class Bar implements Foo
    {
        public function init($str)
        {
            return gettype($str);
        }
    }

    class FooBar implements Foo
    {
        public function init(?string $str)
        {
            return gettype($str);
        }
    }

    $bar = new \Bar();
    $foobar = new \FooBar();

    echo $bar->init('4'). "\r\n";
    echo $bar->init(4);

    echo '<br />';
    echo '=========================================================================';
    echo '<br />';

    echo $foobar->init('4');
    echo $foobar->init(4); # this errors as expected
```

Ideally, I'd like to set the scalar type in the interface to reduce repetition in my classes that implement the interface. Is there a way I can do this? Or do I have to explicitly declare scalar types in all of the classes?

**Edit: Abstract Classes**

My abstract class code:

```
<?php
    declare(strict_types = 1);

    abstract class FooBar
    {
        abstract public function test(?string $str);
    }

    class Trey extends FooBar
    {
        public function test($str)
        {
            return gettype($str);
        }
    }

    $trey = new \Trey();
    echo $trey->test(4); = this works, when I'd expect it to fatal error
```

Same as above, but question applying to abstract classes instead.

Comment: I don't think you can do it. The interface specification is a requirement, not a restriction. The implementation classes are allowed to be more general than the interface requires.

Comment: @Barmar hmm I see .. I'm guessing same applies for abstract classes?

Comment: The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php) says that implementations of abstract methods must have the same type hints. But there's no similar language in the documentation of interfaces.

Comment: Msybe the difference is because a class can implement multiple interfaces, and they each might declare `init()` with different type hints; the implementation has to allow all of them. But there's no multiple inheritance of classes.

Comment: @Barmar I suppose that makes sense, I'll edit my question with new test code with abstract classes - but I think that it's a case of "no, this is not possible"